# How to use operator in Rxjs 6 in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I need some help in Rxjs Operators. I'm working in Angular 6 Project. Rxjs version is 6.1.0
I was facing the issue in Rxjs Operator importing. So I execute this statement with hope to resolve my issues.

```
Statement: npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

And here is my component code.

```
import { AppError } from './../common/validators/app-error';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {

  deletePost(id) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
      .pipe(
        map(res => res),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          Observable.throw(new AppError());
        }));
  }

  private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

}
```

And I'm getting this error with compiled successfully.

```
    i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ERROR in src/app/services/post.service.ts(18,20): error TS2345: Argument of type '(error: HttpErrorResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Response>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
```

How can I use Rxjs successfully? What's the issue here.

Comment: You have to use `catchError` within the pipe, just like you do for `map`

Comment: You're mixing the names of the methods from 5 and earlier with the pipeable operator functions that are required from 6. `.catch` was renamed to `catchError`, because otherwise it clashes with the statement of the same name (see also `.do` -> `tap`, for example - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax).

Comment: Also, what's the point of `map(res => res)`. Do you understand what that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `catchError` within the `pipe` function now, like so:

```
deletePost(id) {
  return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
    .pipe(
       map(res => res),
       catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         return Observable.throw(new AppError());
       }));
}
```

Comment: `i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ERROR in src/app/services/post.service.ts(17,10): error TS2339: Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, {}>'.
src/app/services/post.service.ts(17,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HttpErrorResponse'` Now it is the error.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question? It should work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejhrqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts